# Yeoman generator naming

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I can see that on the Yeoman documentation it explicitly says:

> The name property must be prefixed by generator-. The keywords
>   property must contain "yeoman-generator" and the repo must have a
>   description to be indexed by our generators page.

However my question is, if I were developing a custom generator for private use / private npm (and therefore don't care about having it indexed) would it still matter what name I give to the generator??

Essentially, how does Yeoman figure out which npm modules are generators and which ones are not? Is it based on the module name, or the keywords? (or both)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would still matter as Yeoman (`yeoman-environment`) will look for NPM packages installed anywhere in your npm search path matching `generator-*`.

So the name is important for `yo` to automatically find your generator.

But also note that Yeoman can run generator via paths (`yo ./node_modules/some-generator/app`). In that case, you wouldn't need a specific name.

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I was looking, though just wanted to mention that when running via paths, it should be `yo path/generator/app` including index.js would not work for me :)

Comment: In terms of running via paths, I just realised that if I globally install yeoman, then `yo ./path/generator/app` works, however if I only install it locally and run it locally e.g. `node ./node_modules/.../cli.js path/generator/app` it won't work?

Comment: The error is not the same as passing a totally wrong path (no generator found) - however yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js "cannot find module"

Comment: @luanped `yo` is an executable, you shouldn't run through `node`. You want `./node_modules/_bin/yo etc/etc`.